# How to fix TypeError when using mpmath.nsum() and scipy.special.gamma()?

Tags: python, scipy, mpmath

I am implementing some mathematical formulas in Python and I get the following error when I use `mpmath.nsum()`

> TypeError: ufunc 'gamma' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

## main file

```
import math
from mpmath import nsum
H_n = - nsum(lambda n: P_n(a,b,c,n)*math.log(P_n(a,b,c,n)), [0, math.inf])
```

## function file

```
import math
from scipy.special import gamma, hyp1f1
def P_n(a,b,c,n):
    P = ((gamma(b)*gamma(a+n))/(gamma(a)*gamma(b+n)))*(hyp1f1(a+n,b+n,-c))
    return P
```

When I use the for loop below I get the answers I want.

```
sum = 0.0
for n in range(100):
    sum += rna.P_n(a,b,c,n)*math.log(rna.P_n(a,b,c,n))
```

Any help please? (Note: I am an absolute beginner in Python so I have no idea how to tackle this issue)

Comment: What are your values for a, b, c?

Comment: They will be random variables with a certain probability distribution, but for now I've set them equal to 1.

Comment: You need to provide a minimum example which we can run to help you. The only way to reproduce your error is if I pass a function to `gamma`. I think in your case, a,b, c are random number generator functions as opposed to `int`, `float`, `complex`.

Comment: Probably even `n` needs to be checked for its type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy.special.gamma only works for integer or floating-point arguments, not mpmath's infinite-precision values. Either use `mpmath.gamma` or avoid mpmath and do the summation manually up to a large finite cutoff.